# How to identify if the current tab is the source of message in Broadcast Channel API?

Tags: angular, broadcast-channel

I want to use Broadcast Channel API in my Angular application to maintain logged in state across tabs. But the tab from which the user is logging in needs to run a little different code than the other tabs. I am setting the handler for MessageEvent on application load. As a result, the tab generating the login message is also executing this handler, which it will because message is dispatched to all listeners. But in the listener, I want to be able to identify if the current tab was the source of message, in that case do nothing. Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 0):

As is stated in the MDN docs the broadcast Channel API, it returns a [MessageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) that inherits from [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Message event object has a read-only property [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/source) that can be compared against [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) property, given that you can do a simple condition as follows:

```
if(event.source !== self)
```

You should be able to separate the logic for a sender and receiver.